# Calculating the marginal distribution in the paper Semantic Hashing

Tags: probability-theory, machine-learning

I'm reading the paper Semantic Hashing by Salakhutdinov and Hinton (https://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~rsalakhu/papers/semantic_final.pdf).

They provide the equations

$$
p(v_i=n|\mathbf{h})=Ps(n,\frac{\exp(\lambda_i+\sum_jh_jw_{ij})}{\sum_k\exp(\lambda_k+\sum_jh_jw_{kj})} \tag{1}
$$

and

$$
p(h_j=1|\mathbf{v}) = \sigma(b_j+\sum_iw_{ij}v_i) \tag{2}
$$

where $Ps(n,\lambda)=e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n/n!$, $\sigma(x)=1/(1+e^{-x})$ and $N=\sum_iv_i$.

Then, they state that the marginal distribution over visible count vectors v is:

$$
p(\mathbf{v})=\sum_{\mathbf{h}}\frac{\exp(-E(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{h}))}{\sum_{\mathbf{u},\mathbf{g}}\exp(-E(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{g}))} \tag{3}
$$
where
$$
E(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{h})=-\sum_i\lambda_iv_i+\sum_i\log(v_i!) - \sum_jb_jh_j-\sum_{i,j}v_ih_jw_{ij} \tag{4}
$$

My question is. How to they get to the expression (3)? My math skills are not great and a derivation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Section 2 from the [Exponential Family Harmonium](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/publications/papers/GenHarm3.pdf) paper might be relevant; specifically, equations 6 and 7 give the marginals provided the conditional distributions.

Comment: Also note that according to figure 3 (from the semantic hashing paper) the joint probability has the form $p(\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{h}) \propto \exp\left(- E(\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{h})\right)$ with the energy function $E$ that can be decomposed into unary terms (for the hidden units $\mathbf{h}$ and for the visible units $\mathbf{v}$) and interaction terms (between all combinations $\langle v_i, h_j \rangle$). This model is a general Restricted Boltzmann machine (RBM); you can find a nice inventory of RBMs in Kevin Murphy's textbook, _Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective_, section 27.7.